# What is the most efficient way to install my new outlets?

Tags: wiring, walls, electrical-panel, conduit

An electrician is installing a brand new 200amp panel (*upgrading electric company service*) right next to my existing panel in the basement. My current panel is in the wall flush with the drywall. The electrician says it'll be cheaper to install the new panel surface mounted with the drywall. That doesn't bother me but now I am wondering what the most efficient way to install my 8 new outlets will be.

They will each have a dedicated 20amp double pole breaker and won't be too far from the panel, probably only 4-6 feet. If the panel was in the wall I can wire them normally and then drywall again.

- Since the panel will be out, what is the most efficient way to install them?
  (*The outlets can be positioned right next to each other.*)
- Do I need to run 8 separate conduits to each outlet?
  **OR** Is there a way I can run a bigger size conduit down and then separate into 8 smaller ones for each outlet?

Looking for advice on what to do.

Comment: Are they all on the same side of the panel, or on opposite sides?

Answer (score 3):

Conduit is allowed on the surface, most cable types would require protection.

You can run multiple circuits in one conduit, the NEC has derating requirements that generally limit you to 4 @240v circuits. 8 circuits is 16 current carriers, gets you 50% rating, which is problematic. It can be overcome with #10 wire on 20A circuits, but won't go down that rabbit trail unless asked.

If just straight 240v 20A circuits (without neutrals) the wires could fit 4 circuits of #12 wires in 1/2" conduit, but you will probably find it easier to push the wire through 3/4" conduits.

If you do run in just 2 conduits you would have box fill limits to consider. The calculation can be a bit confusing, but the minimum size box needed for the first receptacle location if you pull extra wires straight through, using grounding raceway, covers, and devices could be as small as 22.5 in³ (8 conductors, 2 for single device yoke, x 2.25 in³ for #12). Depending on cover used you might be able to get away with a 4²x 1.5" deep box, but you best be considering at least 2" deep, and then you probably could fit two devices per 4² box.

You could reduce conduit and box size after the first receptacle, but uniformity has appearance benefits without much sacrifice of space or cost.

Comment: There is a little lattitude for derating in short raceway lengths, but too many rabbit trails without a few more details.

Answer (score 2):

While product recommendations are considered "off topic" here, I'm still going to suggest Wiremold 4000.   Not sure what you're setting up (a "grow" or bitcoin mining operation?, not that it matters).  8 double pole breakers? this has to be a grow. At any rate, the wiremold 4000 is quite large and would accommodate a lot of circuits and gives you lots of flexibility for outlet placement and potential future changes.  Attached is a pic of it installed in my wood working shop.

Even if you don't go with wiremold 4000, you don't need a separate conduit to each outlet, you just need to pay attention to fill capacities of the conduit.  There is no requirement for individual circuits to be in separate conduits. If you choose conduit, consider going with EMT, since that will serve as your ground and reduce the number of wires needed in the conduit. [image: pic of wiremold 4000]

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple EMT conduit, or Legrand Wiremold.

You are allowed to have up to 4 circuits per conduit of 15-20A circuits.

Comment: I don't think his question is clear enough to answer.

Comment: Harper... I think you missed something in the original post. They said, *They will each have a dedicated 20amp double pole breaker*....that's 240, not  a MWBC in all likelyhood, I'm currently cleaning out a rental house that the renters moved out of suddenly and left behind some "grow" lights. I did a bit of research on the make and model of them. The transformers feeding them were all 240v. Also bit coin miners also run more efficiently at 240v.   But who knows, I'm just guessing at what would need much capacity.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Oh, you're right.  That takes the MWBCs out of the picture, but the concept still works.  Those grow lights are worth real money, I'd park em the required amount of time and then sell 'em.  And not all uses are illegal, so you can sell with a clear conscience.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I'm in Washington state so yeah, they are perfectly legal.  Just have to be careful about selling them and where...probably in the parking lot of the big box orange store with a couple of buddies carrying.